# java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException while running test script

Tags: java, vert.x

I got some problem with vert.x flamework (version: '3.8.1').
I got java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException while running the unit test .
There is nothing which will block the thread. I am confuse about it.

TestMainVerticle.java

```java
@ExtendWith(VertxExtension.class)
public class TestMainVerticle {

  @BeforeEach
  void deploy_verticle(Vertx vertx, VertxTestContext testContext) {
    vertx.deployVerticle(new MainVerticle(), testContext.succeeding(id -> testContext.completeNow()));
  }

  @Test
  void verticle_deployed(Vertx vertx, VertxTestContext testContext) throws Throwable {
    testContext.completeNow();
  }
}
```

MainVerticle

```
public class MainVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {


    @Override
    public void start(Promise<Void> startPromise) throws Exception {

    }
}
```

output

```
The test execution timed out. Make sure your asynchronous code includes calls to either VertxTestContext#completeNow(), VertxTestContext#failNow() or Checkpoint#flag()
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: The test execution timed out. Make sure your asynchronous code includes calls to either VertxTestContext#completeNow(), VertxTestContext#failNow() or Checkpoint#flag()
    at io.vertx.junit5.VertxExtension.joinActiveTestContexts(VertxExtension.java:230)
    at io.vertx.junit5.VertxExtension.beforeTestExecution(VertxExtension.java:191)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks$5(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeMethodsOrCallbacksUntilExceptionOccurs(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:169)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:154)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:125)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
...
```

Answer (score 2):

The verticle deployment never completes if the promise is not completed:

```
public class MainVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {


    @Override
    public void start(Promise<Void> startPromise) throws Exception {
        // Complete the promise when the verticle is ready
        startPromise.complete();
    }
}
```